# aws beanstalk single instance 502 proxy error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to configure an aws beanstalk single instance. I've successfully created the instance, but when I navigate to the Environment URL, I get the following error.

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

What could be causing this and what do I need to do to fix it.

I'm deploying a java web app using tomcat.